# knockout.js how to bind dynamic css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Working on learning bootstrap and knockout.js. This is more of a knockout question.

I would like to populate a new row of a table (using addSeat function), and if the name field on that new row is empty, add the bootstrap 'error' class to the row. It is empty by default. Once the name field is entered, the style should change to 'success'.

The basic code is taken from the Seat Reservation samples. Here is the markup:

```
    <div id="food" class="span10">
<h2>Your seat reservations (<span data-bind="text: seats().length"></span>)</h2>

<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr data-bind="css: isnameBlank">
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Remove</a></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat, enable: seats().length < 8">Reserve another seat</button>

<h3 data-bind="visible: totalSurcharge() > 0">
    Total surcharge: $<span data-bind="text: totalSurcharge().toFixed(2)"></span>
</h3>
    </div>
```

Here is the js file:

```
    // Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

    self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
        var price = self.meal().price;
        return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";
    });

    self.isnameBlank = ko.computed(function () {
        var ib = self.name().length;
        console.log(ib);
        return ib == 0 ? "warning" : "success";
    }, self);

}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);

    // Computed data
    self.totalSurcharge = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.seats().length; i++)
            total += self.seats()[i].meal().price;
        return total;
    });

    // Operations
    self.addSeat = function () {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
    }
    self.removeSeat = function (seat) { self.seats.remove(seat) }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel(), document.getElementById('food'));
```

When I run this the console logs the correct length (the ib variable), but the css class does not change.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have this line:

```
var ib = self.name.length;
```

You should be doing this:

```
var ib = self.name().length;
```

This seems to be working just fine when I test it in Chrome. Here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xfv2g/

The only thing I can assume is that you are expecting it to change as they type. In order to do that you will have to change when the `name` field binds by putting the `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` modifier to the [value binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html).

Here is the same fiddle with that being the only difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xfv2g/1/

Comment: Thank you! That is correct and makes the code work correctly (sorry, I must have changed it prior to posting), but the original problem persists - the css doesn't change for the row. I will edit the post above to reflect this change.

Comment: I am using Chrome too. When I looked at the fiddle link you provided I saw that the version was 2.2.1, and then it dawned on me that I was referencing an older one. THANK YOU for your help.

Comment: @vbuser2004 - Yes, the dynamic css binding is new as of 2.2.1, which isn't super clear from the documentation. It was one of a few nice little gems added in that update.